# How to open the newest csv file of a directory in array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, database, csv

So I have this device that create one CSV file and update the data inside the file every 15 minutes and then send a new csv files everyday to our server. So I want to display the latest data in a website.

I have a line of code to load the file using fgetcsv, but this code open a specific csv file in a specific folder.

```php
$f_pointer=fopen("database/student01.csv","r"); // file pointer
$ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
print_r($ar);
```

I would like to find a way to open the newest csv file and data in array so i can make a table from a specific data.

I'm new to web development, any helpful resources would be appreciated. Thank you.

---

### UPDATE

i find a way to open the latest file in directory

```php
function pre_r($array) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($array);
  echo '</pre>';
}

$files = scandir('database/AWLR/2018/10', SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$newest_file = $files[0];

pre_r($newest_file); //file name

//to open file in array
$f_pointer=fopen("database/AWLR/2018/10/$newest_file","r"); // file pointer
$ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
pre_r($ar);
```

but this code open the first row of a csv file while i want to open the last row (since it is the newest data given). and is there a way to change the directory automatically? because this code has to keep update every month

---

### LATEST UPDATE

This code works, unfortunately it display the first row of the csv file,

```php
$current_year = date('Y'); 
$current_month = date('m');
$files = scandir("database/AWLR/".$current_year."/".$current_month, 1); // use 0 for ascending order, and 1 for descending order
$newest_file = $files[0];

pre_r($newest_file); //file name

//to open file in array
$f_pointer=fopen("database/AWLR/".$current_year."/".$current_month."/".$newest_file,'r'); // file pointer
$ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
pre_r($ar);
```

is there a way to display the last row of csv file instead?

This is one of the csv file im talking about

[csv file](https://ln.sync.com/dl/33fc5ca60/rrtdnf7p-xitztefw-abrwbtju-d4qp5w75)

### I've solved the problem, thank you everyone

Comment: What is this device? Can this device set a name on the file? Say filename using Unix? Meaning the filename with the largest number is the latest file.

Comment: it's a data logger, a telemetry device, ya it can set a name with date format (for example: 20181004.CSV) and will send a new csv file every day.

Comment: This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the suggested code you can use and test

```
$current_year = date('Y'); 
$current_month = date('m');
$files = scandir("database/AWLR/".$current_year."/".$current_month, 1); // use 0 for ascending order, and 1 for descending order
$newest_file = $files[0];

pre_r($newest_file); //file name

//to open file in array
$f_pointer=fopen("database/AWLR/".$current_year."/".$current_month."/".$newest_file,'r'); // file pointer
$ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
pre_r($ar);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try the code and inform the result.

Comment: @Waloy, Thanks. Please Up vote this answer if it's working.

Comment: it works but the code display the first row of the csv file, while i want to display the last row (the newest data). I have include one of the csv file in my post. Any idea how to display the last row php or any other languange?

Answer (score 0):

```
    //this is your file path
    $files_location = "database/";

    //this function will return latest file in folder 
    function latest_file_Name ($files_location) {
    //open folder and reads whats inside
    $openDir = opendir($files_location);
    //look for each file in the folder. 
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($openDir))) {
    //ignore the  . and .. these are system folders. you can also ignore any other file if not necesery
    // for Example if($fileName != "." && $fileName != ".." && $fileName != "unwanted_file_name.csv)" in condition 
    if($fileName != "." && $fileName != "..")
    {
    $list[date("YmdHis ", filemtime($files_location.$fileName))]=$fileName; 
    }
    }
    rsort($list);
    $last_file =array_shift(array_values($list));
    return $last_file;
    }

    $last_file_in_folder = latest_file_Name($files_location);
    $f_pointer=fopen("database/".$last_file_in_folder,"r"); // file pointer
    $ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
    print_r($ar);
```

Try this I hope It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try the code and inform the result.
Thank you. This is a great community!!

Comment: Best of luck @Waloy this answer will work regardless of file name or type.....